# Autolayout and aspect ratio to button

Tags: ios, autolayout, aspect-ratio

I have this image but I can't resize properly for each kind of type dimensions of iPhone

The image is in the bottom (More Info button), like this:

[image]

Comment: The entire `More Info` background is an image? (text and background color)

Comment: Its a button on the bottom

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: When I try to preview in different sizes of iPhone the button doesn't change the aspect ratio properly

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this problem only using these constraints thanks!

[image]

[image]